# How do I match a JSON object with a unique ID using regex

Tags: regex, json, match

I have the following JSON object:

```
{ 
  "fieldId": "id1", 
  "isVisibleInDetails": true, 
  "isVisibleInGrid": true, 
  "columnWidth": 142, 
}, 
{ 
  "fieldId": "id2", 
  "isVisibleInDetails": true, 
  "isVisibleInGrid": true, 
  "columnWidth": 100, 
}, 
{ 
  "fieldId": "id3", 
  "isVisibleInDetails": true, 
  "isVisibleInGrid": true, 
  "columnWidth": 159, 
}
```

I want to match the following:

```
{ 
  "fieldId": "id2", 
  "isVisibleInDetails": true, 
  "isVisibleInGrid": true, 
  "columnWidth": 100, 
},
```

I've tried using the regex `(\{.*)id2(.*?)\},` but the match returns as:

```
{ 
  "fieldId": "id1", 
  "isVisibleInDetails": true, 
  "isVisibleInGrid": true, 
  "columnWidth": 142, 
}, 
{ 
  "fieldId": "id2", 
  "isVisibleInDetails": true, 
  "isVisibleInGrid": true, 
  "columnWidth": 100, 
},
```

Can anyone please correct my regex?

Comment: Just as a note, the reason it is bringing in the first object is that `*` is greedy, and will take everything possible that matches, and since there is a "{" at the beginning of the first object, it is including it in the search.

Comment: You should really use a JSON Parser to manipulate/navigate JSON

Comment: I'll be using this regex to match some JSON in an oracle db using PL SQL

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that those are JSON *fragments*, but not valid JSON documents. A JSON parser is not obligated to parse fragments. To be a valid JSON document, you must have a root object (which would either be an object or an arra). You have a series of objects with no root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this regular expression `\{[^{]*id2[^}]*?\}`

Answer (score 0):

I think that knowing what you are trying to do is a very important question, but at a minimum you can use this regex to get exactly what you are looking for:

```
\{[^}]+?id2.*?\}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close..

```
\{[^{}]*id2[^{}]*\}
```

use `[^{}]*` instead of `.*?`

**OR**

```
 \{(?=[^{}]*id2).*?\}
```

---

in your regex `.` would also match `{`,`}` and so it would capture others..use `[^{}]` to avoid matching `{`,`}`